# error getting to admin>stores>configuration page

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

I'm getting an error getting to admin>stores>configuration page. this started after I added a second store. I have removed the second store but I'm still getting this error. I tried to do a backup from an earlier date but still got the error.below is the error. is there a file I need to change to fix this?

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 487061793102

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined index: id in
> /home/customer/www/jefftreece.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
> on line 63","1":"#1
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php:146]\n#2
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php:24]\n#3
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getTabs()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php:209]\n#4
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php:76]\n#5
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getFirstSection()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php:63]\n#6
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#7
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#8
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
> called at [app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php:76]\n#9
> WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#10
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]\n#11
> Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#12
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#13
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
> called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php:39]\n#14
> Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#15
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]\n#16
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#17
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#18
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#19
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
> called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#20
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#21
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#22
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#23
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at
> [index.php:39]\n</pre>","url":"/admin123/admin/system_config/index/key/da8d7fe676f7f0cd30b0f83cc61360b065e967741d167658d7f536be4cf92007/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like your cache or generated folder still relies on some references to the second store you've created.

I suggest 3 things:

- clear manually your folder `generated/*`
- flush the cache; again on this occasion, I would clear the cache manually, emptying `var/cache/*` and `var/page_cahce/*`
- finally, if you use redis, `redis-cli flushall` (if locally installed)

**UPDATE:**
ok, now that I read the full error, I'd be inclined to think it has to do with a third-party module:
`php bin/magento mod:dis WeltPixel_Backend` and then clear cache would be good to know whether that resolves it. If not, I admit the next step is to debug directly your install. For this, it is a long shot my xdebug will reach :-)

Comment: followed your instructions but the same results. any other recommendations. thanks

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: thanks for your help removed weltpixel but the same results. I also went to a backup that was before the issue but the same results. :-(

Comment: Looks like it is either in your database or cache.. likely database I imagine

Comment: is that something I can edit or clean up manually?

Comment: if it is dev environment, best to reinstall it. debugging can be time-consuming. Lesson of the day, keep a db backup going forward